# Python type lines then loop over them till line not in txt file

Tags: python, loops

im trying to log all proxies used during my requests so i dont get the same for the next few, but for some reasons its not working

here's the code which logs used proxies

```
proxy_list = open('proxies.txt', 'a+')
    proxy_list.write(proxy)
    def renew_connection():
       with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
           controller.authenticate(password="password")
           controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
    renew_connection()
    session = get_tor_session()
    proxy1 = (session.get("http://api.ipify.org/").text)
    while proxy1 in proxy_list:
        def renew_connection():
          with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
               controller.authenticate(password="password")
               controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        renew_connection()
        session = get_tor_session()
        proxy2 = (session.get("http://api.ipify.org/").text)
        if proxy2 not in proxy_list:
            break
```

edit:

```
78.159.103.53
78.159.103.53
185.220.102.249
51.81.83.146
51.81.83.146
51.81.83.140
51.81.83.140
198.251.89.198
185.220.102.243
185.220.102.243
91.109.29.78
45.151.167.10
```

output of your code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clear, but I think I understand what you're trying to do.

- Get used proxy list
- Renew connection until a new proxy is found
- Add new proxy to used list

Try this code:

```
def renew_connection():
   with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
       controller.authenticate(password="password")
       controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

with open('proxies.txt') as f:  # current proxy list
    proxy_list = f.readlines()

renew_connection()
session = get_tor_session()
proxy1 = (session.get("http://api.ipify.org/").text)

while proxy1 in proxy_list:
    renew_connection()
    session = get_tor_session()
    proxy1 = (session.get("http://api.ipify.org/").text)
        
with open('proxies.txt', 'a') as f:  # add new proxy
    f.write(proxy1)
```